# Error using `numba` on an empty list in a `for` loop

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm using python 2.7 and `numba` version `0.24.0`.

I am trying to speed up my code with numba.  In my code, I create an empty `list`, I create a bunch of `numpy` arrays, I append them to a `list` as I create them, and I `np.vstack` them together at the end to form one big `numpy.array`.

However, I get an error when I try to do this.  I have created a reproducible snippet of the problem below:

```
from numba.decorators import autojit
import numpy as np

def mult(x):
    y = []
    for _ in range(4):
        y.append(x)
    return np.vstack(y)

jit_mult = autojit(mult)
foo = jit_mult(np.random.randn(2, 2))

>> ValueError: Cannot type empty list
```

Whereas a slight change removes the error:

```
from numba.decorators import autojit
import numpy as np

def mult(x):
    y = []
    y.append(x) # This line was added
    for _ in range(3):
        y.append(x)
    return np.vstack(y)

jit_mult = autojit(mult)
foo = jit_mult(np.random.randn(2, 2))
```

Why is this?

Comment: it works great with a newer version, update numba is not an option ?

Comment: The current release of numba is 0.33 with 0.34 probably coming out soon. I would update since it's a fast moving project if possible.

Comment: Updating numba solved my problem.  Please post it as an answer so I can give credit for solving the problem.  I am now using version `0.34.0`